# Updating nested array elements in mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to know how can we access nested array elements in MongoDB
For example, if we have something like :

```
{
   array1 : [
      {
         array11 : {
               name11 : "xyz"
            }
       },{
         array12 : {
             name12: "abc",
             nums : [1,2,3,4]
          }
       }
     ]
}
```

Now how can I access and update the "name12" field.
And how can I add elements to "nums" field.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I'm using node js

Answer (score 1):

A) To find the collection :  I am assuming you want to find name12 = "abc".

```
 db.mydata.find({"array1.array12.name12":"abc"}).pretty()
```

B) To update & Add elements to the nums array use the positional operator :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```
db.mydata.update({"array1.array12.name12":"abc"},
             {$set:{"array1.$.name12":"abc"} , 
              $push:{"array1.$.nums":5}
})
```

On a side note, you should consider redefining your schema so that the arrays have similar structures. It will help you to update in the long run..

Answer (score -1):

you can access it like any traditional js array, in this case, youre accessing objects within arrays so take care of the syntax.